# Android Background Service or Receiver to check the internet connection in the background

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

In my application I am always connected to the openfire server with the help of the internet. Now if the connection is lost in between or disconnected, I want that it should give a popup and on the press of the OK button it should relogin the person( as when the connection to the server is lost - even for 1 secs the person is disconnected).

I m using the following code:

```
public class ConnectionCheck extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =  (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        NetworkInfo mobileNetInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if(activeNetInfo!=null){
            Toast.makeText( context, "Active Network Type : " + activeNetInfo.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }

         if( mobileNetInfo != null )
            {
              Toast.makeText( context, "Mobile Network Type : " + mobileNetInfo.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }

    }
```

Suppose when wifi is disconnected it connects to the mobile network again( but internally the user is not connected to the server)

What should i do for the same, i.e when the user is disconnected - even for one sec from the server then it should give a popup.

Is it possible??

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**-** Your above code would only check the connectivity of your android device to the **wifi router or to the Phone's Data packet service**, but it **won't check if the wifi really do have the internet connection working or not.**

**-** I was once struck finding this solution when i was working on a project, i tried looking it over stackoverflow for a solution, but what i got was the piece of code just as yours. **So i created my own solution.**

I needed to do some custom work..but got it up and running...

My code switches from Wifi to Mobile network when its off.

And I am using the TimeService at port 37 to know that the Internet is DEAD while the wifi connection is still ON

Now i am putting here a complete working code i made. Please pardon me as the `DRY` (Don't Repeat Yourself Principle ) **has been abused here**. So please refactor the code and convert the duplicate codes into method , ie into a `single sensible place`, when using in production network

```
/////---------------------------Intial Available Network Checking



private boolean checkConnection(){


boolean connected = false;
ConnectivityManager cm =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

if (cm != null) {
NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();

for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
if ((ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI")
|| ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
& ni.isConnected() & ni.isAvailable()) {
connected = true;
     }

   }
 }


return connected;
} /////---------------------------Intial Available Network Checking
```

/////-------------------------------Check for the working Internet Connection

```
public boolean inetAddr(){

    boolean x1 = false;


    try {
        Socket s = new Socket("utcnist.colorado.edu", 37);

        InputStream i = s.getInputStream();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(i);

        while(scan.hasNextLine()){

            System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
            x1 = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {


            x1 = false;
    } 

    return x1;

}

/////-------------------------------Check for the working Internet Connection


////-------------------------------Check Mobile Conectivity Again

public boolean mobileConnect(){

    boolean conn = false;
    ConnectivityManager cm =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNet = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if(activeNet != null){

        conn = true;
    }else{

        conn = false;
    }

    return conn;



}

////------------------------------Check Mobile Conectivity Again
```

**Here i am using the Above Methods....**

```
try{    
     if (!checkConnection()){


         AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YumZingSplashActivity.this);
         myAlertDialog.setTitle("--- Connectivity Check ---");
         myAlertDialog.setMessage("No Internet Connectivity");
         myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

            YumZingSplashActivity.this.finish();
            //splashHandler.removeCallbacks(launcherRunnable);

          }});
            System.out.println("No Internet Connectivity");

            myAlertDialog.show();           




        }
        else{


              if(inetAddr()){
            aphandle = APIHandling.getInstance();
            aphandle.xmlCreateSession();
            System.out.println("Net Connectivity is Present");
            DURATION = Integer.valueOf(getString(R.string.splash_duration));



            splashHandler = new Handler();

            //  ================ Main Code of the Application
            launcherRunnable = new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    Intent i = new Intent(YumZingSplashActivity.this, YumZingTabHostActivity.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                    YumZingSplashActivity.this.finish();
                }
            };
            if (DEBUG)
            {
                splashHandler.post(launcherRunnable);
            }
            else{


                splashHandler.postDelayed(launcherRunnable, DURATION);
            }

        }
              else{

                  if(mobileConnect()){


                      if(inetAddr()){
                      aphandle = APIHandling.getInstance();
                        aphandle.xmlCreateSession();
                        System.out.println("Net Connectivity is Present");
                        DURATION = Integer.valueOf(getString(R.string.splash_duration));



                        splashHandler = new Handler();

                        //  ================ Main Code of the Application
                        launcherRunnable = new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {
                                Intent i = new Intent(YumZingSplashActivity.this, YumZingTabHostActivity.class);
                                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(i);
                                YumZingSplashActivity.this.finish();
                            }
                        };
                        if (DEBUG)
                        {
                            splashHandler.post(launcherRunnable);
                        }
                        else{


                            splashHandler.postDelayed(launcherRunnable, DURATION);
                        }
                      }else{

                          AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YumZingSplashActivity.this);
                         myAlertDialog.setTitle("--- Connectivity Check ---");
                         myAlertDialog.setMessage("No Internet Connectivity");
                         myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                          public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                            YumZingSplashActivity.this.finish();
                            //splashHandler.removeCallbacks(launcherRunnable);

                          }});
                            System.out.println("No Internet Connectivity");

                            myAlertDialog.show();       
                      }
                  }else{




                         AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YumZingSplashActivity.this);
                         myAlertDialog.setTitle("--- Connectivity Check ---");
                         myAlertDialog.setMessage("No Internet Connectivity");
                         myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                          public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                            YumZingSplashActivity.this.finish();
                            //splashHandler.removeCallbacks(launcherRunnable);

                          }});
                            System.out.println("No Internet Connectivity");

                            myAlertDialog.show();           






                  }

              }
        }

     //setContentView(R.layout.yumzing_splash_layout);
    }  catch(Exception ex){

            System.out.println("Leak ko catch");
        }



    }
```

Comment: @GauravArora i usually use this code just before making a call over the internet, so you can use it over there inorder to prevent unnecessary overhead, or you if you want you can use this in the broadcast receiver, but  that would be bit heavier.....

Comment: but my case if different bro. I want to check all the time, as mine application is always connected to the server. If it is not connected to the server then I have to give a popup

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra The another issue that you have raised about the data not present or internet is a dead network uses a url and a port. Now, If I use any url and port `37` then it should work ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this service Class. Just set the time interval in seconds and the url to ping:

[Android Check Internet Connection](https://github.com/oscarjiv91/Android-Check-Internet-Connection)

Just remember to add the service to the Manifest file, and add the permissions

Comment: Is there a way to return data to UIThread? I tried many times but i couldn't get it done.